# Converting a string to a double precision in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I convert a string `17,74320512` to a double precision in PostgreSQL ?

I tried:

```
select cast(`17,74320512` as double precision);

ERROR: invalid syntax for double precision type: '17,74320512'
```

But i can not change format of the number(`17,74320512`) because i imported it from .txt file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `to_number()` and chose the [`format`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-string-functions/postgresql-to_number/) that best suits your strings and locale, e.g.

```
SELECT 
  to_number('17,74320512','999D99999999'),
  to_number('17,74320512','999D99999999')::double precision;

  to_number  |  to_number  
-------------+-------------
 17.74320512 | 17.74320512
```